# Run a gem from rvm with runit

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I need to create a runit service that runs a gem's binary that was installed with rvm, the problem is that a non-login bash shell, which is how runit runs its services does not have the correct path's for rvm. Is there any automatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

I use following script:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                   
exec 2>&1                                                                                              

DIR=/var/www/apps/mega_app/current                                                                       
export rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm                                                                         
export rvm_ignore_rvmrc=1                                                                              
cd $DIR                                                                                                
exec chpst -u user:group /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ree exec bundle exec ${DIR}/daemons/mega_daemon.rb
```

Comment: This script is capable only with system-wide RVM. Maybe you know how to run it with per-user RVM?

Answer (score 1):

Does `su - USERNAME -c '/path/to/script'` work? It should preserve the $PATH variables.