# Start Unicorn with Runit and User's RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, chef-infra, unicorn, runit

I'm deploying my Rails App servers with Chef. Have just swapped to RVM from a source install of Ruby (because I was having issues with my deploy user).

Now I have my deploy sorted, assets compiled and bundler's installed all my gems.

**The problem I have is supervising Unicorn with Runit..**

RVM is not installed as root user - only as my deploy user has it, as follows:

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies    
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

I can manually start Unicorn successfully from my deploy user. However, it won't start as part of runit.

My run file looks like this. I have also tried the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124541/run-a-gem-from-rvm-with-runit) unsuccessfully..

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/deploy/production/current
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -u deploy:deploy /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn_production.rb
```

If I run it manually, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
```

I created a small script ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/simonmorley/6372864)) which does run as root. However, if I call this from runit, I see the workers start but I get two processes for runit and I can't stop or restart the service:

Output of ps:

```
1001     29062     1  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 unicorn master -D -E production -c /var/www/html/deploy/production/current/config/unicorn_production.rb                                                                                                                    
1001     29065 29062  9 00:08 ?        00:00:12 unicorn worker[0] -D -E production -c /var/www/html/deploy/production/current/config/unicorn_production.rb                                                                                                                 
root     29076   920  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 su - deploy -c cd /var/www/html/deploy/production/current; export GEM_HOME=/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247; /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/unicorn -D -E production -c /var/www/html/deploy/production/current/config/unicorn_production.rb
1001     29083 29076  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 -su -c cd /var/www/html/deploy/production/current; export GEM_HOME=/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247; /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/unicorn -D -E production -c /var/www/html/deploy/production/current/config/unicorn_production.rb
```

What should I do here? Move back to monit which worked nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your run file is doing it wrong, you are using the binary without setting the environment, for that purpose you should use wrappers:

```
rvm wrapper ruby-2.0.0-p247 --no-links unicorn
```

To simplify the script use alias so it does not need to be changed when you decide which ruby should be used:

```
rvm alias create my_app_unicorn ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

And change the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/deploy/production/current
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -u deploy:deploy /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/my_app_unicorn/unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn_production.rb
```

This will ensure proper environment is used for execution of `unicorn` and any time you want change ruby used to run it just crate alias to a new ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've run both the wrapper and alias as deploy user (assuming so because root doesn't have access to rvm). However runit still won't start it and if I run manually as root, it gives: ruby_noexec_wrapper not found.

Comment: That's actually done it. Needed to kill the daemons a few times. Thanks, happy days :)